# Adding proxy support to Selenium multi session opening script in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I recently made a script that allow me to create multiple Browser sessions targeting one URL. I would like to add proxy support to it in order to not get banned when running it. I tried to use the Proxy lib from selenium but it just get ignored. 
My Question : How can I add proxy support into this script while using Selenium in python ? (each session will get a random proxy) 
Here is my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `stem` library which allows you to use Tor in python. Read the docs [here](https://stem.torproject.org/api.html) to see how to use it.

The two basic parts missing from your code are the following:

1. `from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType`
2. `chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=#yourproxyhere#'`
3. Tor!

Here you can see how I set up my stem + selenium project:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from time import sleep
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

#this gives you a new identity 
with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
  #set the proxy in selenium to 127.0.0.1:9150 and have your Tor Browser open!

link = 'https://some-link.com' #target url
prox= 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150' #Here you connect to your localhost which connects to a Tor network
#some chrome_options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % prox) 
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=400,600") 


#the following also deactivates location tracking!
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation" :2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(link)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, i added the selenium.webdriver.common.proxy and added the proxy into the chrome_options.add_argument, but the thing is i don't want to use tor i would like to use a txt file as proxy source in order to use private proxies i bought. Now with arguments added the command prompt shows --TypeError: add_argument() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given--

Comment: I think the problem might be that you have 2 arguments in your `chrome_options.add_argument`. I would never do it this way, I edited my original response

Comment: I saw that the thing is that i managed to find another way to achieve my goal, proxies just still get ignored lol need to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of my code including the new proxy support elements, I want it to use proxies form a txt file via a  `proxies = read_from_txt("proxies.txt")` and randomly rotate between them using random lib :

Thank you for quick replies, really appreciate it.